# Why does Microsoft Windows 10 File Explorer keep changing permissions on a folder back to 'Read Only', even though I supposedly have full control?

Tags: directory, permissions

I can move and delete files in the folder manually, in File Explorer.  But my C# program, which attempts to delete a file, always throws an error, System.UnauthorizedAccessException.

Comment: What user is your app running under? Console.WriteLine(System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name)

Comment: It's running as some user which was evidently created when Windows 10 was installed, and which I can't seem to locate in User Accounts.  This program is an ordinary Windows Form app which used to run without problem, until I had a catastrophic system crash ("Missing operating system" - thanks to a blunder by a Microsoft support person) and had to reinstall Windows 10 from scratch.  Now the app has been "regenerated" as a Windows Core app, which seems to be the source of the problem.

Comment: Since you can't provide permissions to "some user", then you will have to run the application under a user with permissions to delete the folder you want. You can try "runas", or switch the user context in the app code itself

Comment: This is all happening using Visual Studio 2019.  So I obtained a copy of Visual Studio 2010, which was the original development environment, and now it runs - again - without problem.